# How to echo second column with only the primary key - SQL/PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to create a fixture list for a football competition currently, and i have been stuck with trying to display something like "team1name V team2name".The tables that i am trying to pull the data from are:

Team

- teamID
- teamname

Fixtures

- hometeam
- awayteam

The sql query I have written up is:

```
$sql = "SELECT homeTeam, awayTeam, roundID, teamID, teamName, logo, groundName, abbreviatedName, matchDate, matchTime, venue 
FROM fixtures 
INNER JOIN team ON fixtures.homeTeam = team.teamID 
INNER JOIN ground ON ground.groundID = team.groundID";
$results =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());
```

and the PHP code which i have been using to display this data is:

```
<?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
{ 
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row ["teamName"]?></td>
                <td> V  </td>
                <td><?php echo $row ["teamName"]></td>

            </tr>
<?php 
}
     mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

I understand i am calling teamname twice and hence why i am getting the same name displayed, but i am unsure as to how to get my code to differentiate the two IDs and names. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is just a SQL problem. You need to join `team` twice, once for home team and once for away team.

```
SELECT homeTeamID, awayTeamID, homeTeam.teamID homeTeamID,
   awayTeam.teamID awayTeamID, homeTeam.teamName homeTeamName,
   awayTeam.teamName awayTeamName
FROM fixtures 
INNER JOIN team homeTeam ON fixtures.homeTeam = homeTeam.teamID 
INNER JOIN team awayTeam ON fixtures.awayTeam = awayTeam.teamID 
INNER JOIN ground ON ground.groundID = team.groundID
```

By naming the selects, you can use the separately in your PHP code.

```
<?php echo $row['homeTeamName']; ?> v <?php echo $row['awayTeamName']; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, tried this i'm getting an error "Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given". Also updated my sql select query in the original question as i found some errors from using one of my test files.